# CF Pagination - How to Indicate the Page a User is on?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Ray Camden has an excllent guide on pagination in CF:
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2006/4/24/ColdFusion-and-Pagination

The problem is that there is no indicator as to what page a user is on. By indicator I mean, for example, if I search for "pizza" on Google and I go to page 4, then page 4 is not a link. It's in black, regular text, and differentiates itself from the other page numbers which are links.
http://www.google.com/#q=pizza&start=30

I would like to know what changes need to be made to Ray's pagination tutorial so users know what page they are on?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: i tried the following code, but no luck:

<cfset pageCount = pageCount + 1>
<cfset pageLink = pageLink + perpage>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ray's code, your page number will be :

```
<cfoutput>
#val( (url.start / perpage ) + 1)#
</cfoutput>
```

(one based pages, i.e. first page is page one, not zero)

Answer (score 0):

use parameter like request.maxrows (i.e how items should be shown per page), thereby also letting you deduct the current page by using

```
start/maxrows = page
```

(you may need to alter this slightly)